# Jira Api Error when creating issue

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

On my website I have a contact form which when submitted, creates a new service desk ticket. It makes the following rest api call:

https://jira-housters.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/request (with appropriate Accept and Authorization request headers)

```
{
"serviceDeskId": "1",
"requestTypeId": "1",
"requestFieldValues": {
"summary": "Housters Contact from Justin Test (Web)",
"description": "test message"
},
"raiseOnBehalfOf": "myemail@mydomain.com"
}
```

Before this worked completely fine, however a few days ago it started erroring:

```
{"errorMessage":"Your request could not be created. Please check the fields have been correctly filled in. Please provide a valid value for field 'Raise this request on behalf of'","i18nErrorMessage":{"i18nKey":"sd.validation.request.creation.failure.required.field","parameters":["Please provide a valid value for field 'Raise this request on behalf of'"]}}
```

This makes no sense, as it's complaining about the raise request on behalf of field when I clearly have it specified. What gives?

Comment: I think that raiseOnBehalfOf requires a username, not an email. I haven't tried it, but generally Jira doesn't associate users by email address

Comment: This has been working for months with passing the email address. It would create a user account for the user automatically. These are requests coming from customers, so they don't have a jira account. Perhaps now I need to manually create a user account first or something...

Answer (score 0):

raiseOnBehalfOf should have the customers accountId not email.

You can create a customer using:-

-> https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/customer

-> Get the accountId from the response.